# Change image when a cell is selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

In my application I have an UITableView in the left as a menu. When I press a cell of the table, the view in the right change.
My "menu" table have customs cells and I want to change the image of the cell when this is selected. How can I do that?

CODE:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
    CRMMenuCell *cell = (CRMMenuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell){

        NSArray * topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CRMMenuCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObjetc in topLevelObjects){

            if ([currentObjetc isKindOfClass:[CRMMenuCell class]]){

                cell = (CRMMenuCell *)currentObjetc;
                break;
            }

        }

    }



    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.labelMenu.text = NSLocalizedString(@"calendarioKey", @"");
        cell.imagenMenu.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendario_gris"];

    }





- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
    CRMMenuCell *cell = (CRMMenuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    if (!cell){

        NSArray * topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CRMMenuCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObjetc in topLevelObjects){

            if ([currentObjetc isKindOfClass:[CRMMenuCell class]]){

                cell = (CRMMenuCell *)currentObjetc;
                break;
            }

        }

    }


    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {

        cell.imagenMenu.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendario_rojo"];


    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do so in the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

delegate of your TableView.

How to change the image depends on your implementation but it should be something like:

```
CRMMenuCell *cell = (CRMMenuCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.myImage = newImage;
```

Edit:
Try following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CRMMenuCell *cell = (CRMMenuCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.imagenMenu.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendario_gris"];
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i am not able to found the solution, I have edited the question.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that my cell is a custom cell and my properties (image, label, etc) isn't in a normal UITableCellView.

Comment: Edited my answer. If you are using different cells you may have to validate the indexPath before casting and changing the image

Comment: How can I change the image back, when the cell isn't highlighted anymore?

Comment: Chris, try the opposite of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, which is didDeselectRowAtIndexPath.